# How to make a recurrent relation out of a for loop relation

Tags: java, for-loop, recursion

That's my first post and also I'm very new to Java and was trying to make a small program that would give all the unique numbers that have the digits from 0 to given number. So for example for input: 4 the output would be:

```
    1234
    1243
    1324
    1342
    1423
    ....
```

and so on, 4 would also mean that the output is gonna be in a range 
1000 < x < 10000 where x is output.

I've tried to make so recurrent relation method but couldn't find anything helpful. So instead I made a for loop relation that would give what I want, but only working for the input of 4. I also have a method that checks if the number is unique. `boolean check(int[] array) {...}` It return `true` if the the number is unique

```
public static void thing(int num) {
        int[] arr = new int[num];
        for(int a = 1; a <= 4; a++) {
            arr[0] = a;
            for(int b = 0; b <= 4; b++) {
                arr[1] = b;
                for(int c = 0; c <= 4; c++) {
                    arr[2] = c;
                    for(int d = 0; d <= 4; d++) {
                        arr[3] = d;
                        if(check(arr)) {
                            System.out.println(arr[0] + "" + arr[1] + "" + arr[2] + "" + arr[3]); 
//here in the result it would print the array like in fibonacci I guess 
                        }   
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So, for now, I need to control the number of loops I need for every case and what I need is the depth to be set by input. And again as I said earlier, the output in the form:

```
    1234
    1243
    ....
    ....
    4312
    4321
```

the order doesn't matter yet it runs. If I'm wrong thinking that recurrence would solve the problem, help me find what would. 
Thanks

Comment: What you're looking for  is a `recursive algorithm` to calculate `permutations`  Just do a web search and you will find them.  `Wikipedia` would be a good start.

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by WJS, you are looking for permutation algorithm. There are many different approaches, but this is one is an easy one:

```
class HeapAlgo {
    //Prints the array
    private void printArr(int a[], int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    //Generating permutation using Heap Algorithm
    private void heapPermutation(int a[], int size, int n) {
        // if size becomes 1 then prints the obtained
        // permutation
        if (size == 1)
            printArr(a, n);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            heapPermutation(a, size - 1, n);

            // if size is odd, swap first and last
            // element
            if (size % 2 == 1) {
                int temp = a[0];
                a[0] = a[size - 1];
                a[size - 1] = temp;
            }

            // If size is even, swap ith and last
            // element
            else {
                int temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[size - 1];
                a[size - 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    // Driver code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HeapAlgo obj = new HeapAlgo();
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
        obj.heapPermutation(a, a.length, a.length);
    }
}
```

Source: [heap permutations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/heaps-algorithm-for-generating-permutations/)

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what needed/been thinking of! But I don't really understand why do you need an object `HeapAlgo obj = new HeapAlgo();` to run it?

Comment: @МаксимШинский  Because he is running it from the `static context` of main.  So he needed to create an instance to invoke the instance method.

Comment: This code is using recursion, so it will be slow down a lot for larger numbers